# Passing a model to an added to DOM popup window in Grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

Here is the problem:

I have a page e.g www.app.com/home and I have some windows that are added in a slide way to the DOM via jquery. One of those windows has the functionality of looking into a gmail account for contacts.

This is done in this way:

1. User is in the home page.
2. Clicks the search Friends button, and a window with many options
   slides in (added by jquery, rthe content is in another .gsp)
3. Clicks the option gmail and it redirects to googles oauth,
   permissions and account selection, where he must accept the access
   to his/her contact list.
4. Once accepted, it redirects to my home page again, where I have a
   var to know if its the callback from google, so I ran the script
   that shows the popup again.

The problem Im having, is that from the home page itself, I can access the model passed by the controller that has the ${friendList}, but when I add some code to the popup window, the ${friendList} is not detected.

Comment: How are you passing the code to the popup window?

Comment: Ey burt, I load it with something like $('#divname').load(page url)

Answer (score 0):

I have used grails render templates to solve this problem in the past. You can have a hidden div that jquery unhides when it is popped up. e.g

```
<div id="theSlideWindow" style="display:none">
    <g:render template="gsptemplate"  collection="${friendList}" var="myfriend" />
</div>
```

Now when the button is clicked, jquery will unhide the div and animate it however you are animating it. Now this is not very efficient depending on the size of friendList because it is loaded with every refresh.

But you can still make jquery load work by doing the following:

1. add user id to a hidden input.

   ```
   <input type="hidden" value="${userid}"/>
   ```
2. use jquery so send the id as a param:

   ```
   $('button').click(function() {
       var page = "gspurl/show?userid=" + $("#hidden").val();
       $("div").load(page, function(response, status, xhr) {
        //do something here
       });
       return false;
   });
   ```
3. In your gsp use userid to load friendList.

Another alternative would be to use a controller that returns html or json instead of a gsp.

Obviously, there several different ways of passing friendList around but hope this gives you some ideas.